# Are the stories in the fictional show Night Springs original?

Tags: video-games, inspiration, the-twilight-zone, alan-wake

In the Alan Wake video game there are several "episodes" of a fictional TV show called Night Springs that is clearly influenced by the Twilight Zone. Are these stories in this show taken from anywhere in particular, or are they original bits of fiction created for the game?

Comment: Mentioning which "episodes" you're thinking of would go a long way here to make this a better question so that we may help you.

Comment: @phantom42: The question has an accepted answer, but for future readers: During the game "Alan Wake", the titular character will occasionally come across tv sets. On those, he (and thus, the player) can watch a tv show called "Night Springs". It is the episodes of this tv show (that exists only in the game) the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an [interview](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/features/archive/2015/11/18/remedy-s-favorite-tv-shows-and-the-time-travel-movies-influencing-quantum-break.aspx?PostPageIndex=1) with Remedy's Creative Director, Sam Lake, he explicitly confirmed that the "**[Night Springs](http://alanwake.wikia.com/wiki/Night_Springs)**" shows were written by Mikko Rautalahti.

> *A surprise absence on Sam Lake's list was Twilight Zone. It was a show
> we wrongfully assumed would be a favorite of Lake's, considering the
> allusions to it throughout Alan Wake. When asked about the show, Lake
> said, "I used to watch, but I never was a huge fan. There were some
> episodes that would stay with you, but as a whole? It just fit the
> tone and stylization of Alan Wake.*
>
> ***Mikko Rautalahti, senior writer,
> well he’s actually story team manager is his title these days, he is
> more of a Twilight Zone fan and he wrote all the Night Springs
> episodes."***
>
> <sub><sup>[Remedy’s Top TV Shows And The Time-Travel Movies Influencing Quantum Break](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/features/archive/2015/11/18/remedy-s-favorite-tv-shows-and-the-time-travel-movies-influencing-quantum-break.aspx?PostPageIndex=1)</sup></sub>

According to the game's Head of Development Oskari Hakkinen, the look and feel of 'Night Springs' was *inspired* by the Twilight Zone but there's no indication that the stories were anything other than wholly original creations.

> **Alan Wake was known for being inspired Stephen King, David Lynch, Twin Peaks, that sort of thing so, aside from the Twilight Zone, what
> other inspirations have been brought into the mix?**
>
> *Twilight Zone would be for the packaging, because **this is an episode of Night Springs and Night Springs was inspired by The Twilight Zone.**
> The inspirations for American Nightmare are a lot of grindhouse,
> classic Americana, B-movie classics, classic sci-fi, From Dusk Till
> Dawn, Quentin Tarantino. The story is very pulp fiction, as opposed to
> Stephen King and David Lynch. The setting is different, you’re in
> Arizona, you’ve got the drive-in theatre, roadside motels, mountaintop
> observatory with a secret message from the stars. All very B-movie
> inspired.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Making Alan Wake’s American Nightmare: An Interview with Remedy’s Oskari Hakkinen](http://www.godisageek.com/2012/02/interview-remedys-oskari-hakkinen/)</sup></sub>